# Flask: Firebase orderBy must be a valid JSON encoded path

Tags: python, flask

I use Flask and Firebase.

I push some values to the database and i want to get for example some data which its id=1 . So , i want to write some Complex Queries.

Heres my app.route :

```
@app.route('/satis', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def satis():
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        users_by_score = db.child("names").order_by_child("id").equal_to(2).get()
        us=users_by_score
        return render_template('satis.html', u=us.val())
    return render_template('satis.html')
```

Heres is index.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        {% for l in u %}
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <h4>{{l}}</h4>
                </li>
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

And this is the error :

```
 "error" : "orderBy must be a valid JSON encoded path"
```

This is my Firebase Real Time Database :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using flutter with firebase, so not sure if it solves the issue but when passing orderBy field it should be in double quotes in resulting url. eg:

[https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy="height"&startAt=3&print=pretty](https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy=%22height%22&startAt=3&print=pretty)

Here you can provide height with escaping pattern such as "\"height\""